# Ansible SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: ssl, ansible

We are trying to install docker engine via the following ansible task.

```
- name: Install docker
  yum:
    name: "http://get.docker.com/rpm/1.7.0/centos-6/RPMS/x86_64/docker-engine-1.7.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm"
    validate_certs: no
    state: present
```

We are getting the below error while executing the above

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {“changed”: false, “msg”: “Failure
>   downloading
>   http://get.docker.com/rpm/1.7.0/centos-6/RPMS/x86_64/docker-engine-1.7.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm,
>   Request failed: “}

Are we missing anything, do we need to install any SSL related packages of Python? 
Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: since it's using http, you may want to remove ```validate_certs``` as that's specifically used when the endpoint is in fact https

Comment: We tried by removing validate_certs option. That time we got another error .

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to validate the SSL certificate for get.docker.com:443. Make sure your managed systems have a valid CA certificate installed. If the website serving the url uses SNI you need python >= 2.7.9 on your managed machine   The exception msg was: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:492: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure."}

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I'm running into the same "sslv3 alert handshake failure"